# Java game loop causing Ubuntu to freeze

Tags: 14.04, java, games

I have been doing front and back end web programming for over a year now, and now I am trying to learn 2D game programming in Java. Based on various sources on the web as well as one from my friend who is an experienced game developer, this is a typical setup:

> > **[Window.java](https://bpaste.net/show/15e6ee2e7099)** | Window setup class
> >
> > **[Game.java](https://bpaste.net/show/c94f2525cb86)** | Main game class

But when I attempt to run the `Game` class, the frame opens and then freezes, the only thing I have control of is my mouse, nothing else. I know the problem occurs in the `render` method, because the program runs fine when that method has an empty body.

I copied the code exactly from the tutorial in which it runs fine, and my friend who sent me an almost identical version which works on his computer, causes the same freeze for me. In both the tutorial and my friend's testing, the operating system is Windows, which causes me to believe that this is strictly an Ubuntu/Linux problem.

I have an Intel i7 3.4gHZ processor, and 8 gigs of RAM, so processing and memory shouldn't be the issue here. Any ideas of what is going on? I know that this is more of a programming question, but the fact that the problem seems to be Ubuntu-specific leads me to post it here.

**EDIT**

I've isolated the problem to one line in the Game class: `bs.show()`. For some reason, it is freezing as soon as I try to show the buffer strategy. If I create the buffer strategy with 1 buffer, it works fine, with anything greater than 1, it freezes.

When it froze the most recent time, I opened a virtual desktop and ran `top`, the weirdest thing is that Java was taking up less than 2% CPU and 6% memory. That just doesn't add up. I really need some help for what is going on here, I've gone about as far as I can go and I don't want to force any more restarts on my machine.

Comment: what version of java are you running? If you need proprietary Java instead of opensource, check this out http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: How would I know if I need proprietary? And I keep my JDK up to date, 1.7 currently

Comment: Does your friend use proprietary? You haven't narrowed it down to a problem with Ubuntu otherwise. It could be a problem with the version of Java if you are using opensource and he/she is not.

Comment: He uses open source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem when running your code. It seems to be a performance issue. To fix it, add`System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");` to the main method in Game.java like this,

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
    new Game();
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the main awt-thread itself.  It should be left alone to cater to the User Responsiveness.  Read up a bit about using the `SwingUtilities2.invokeLater` and `SwingUtilities2.invokeAndWait` methods to get rid of this freezing window issues in the Java Swing Applications.

The approach would be to:

> 1) Do your extensive stuff in a Runnable (you are using one)
>
> 2) In your main method, pass on the Runnable instance to one of above
>   two methods in the SwingUtilities2 class

If you want to go further, you can also consider using Worker Threads.